# How to Integrate 'premailer' with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, premailer

How does one integrate the '[premailer](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer)' gem with a Rails (3.0.7) project? I currently have in my mailer:

```
def welcome(user)
  @user = user

  mail to: user.email, subject: "Welcome"
end
```

But I can't figure out how to integrate the library. I need to call:

```
premailer = Premailer.new(html)
html = premailer.to_inline_css
```

However, I'm not sure how to access the contents of my email from a mailer action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
def premailer(message)
  message.text_part.body = Premailer.new(message.text_part.body.to_s, with_html_string: true).to_plain_text
  message.html_part.body = Premailer.new(message.html_part.body.to_s, with_html_string: true).to_inline_css

  return message
end

def welcome(user)
  @user = user

  message = mail to: user.email, subject: "Welcome"
end
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to take care of the mail body quite well.. Thanks.. . How can I use premailer to include the layout css inline as well along with mail body, as one complete mail..?

Comment: can you explain why this is working? It's not quite self-explaining, at least not for me

Comment: I don't get it. When is this premailer method called? Doesn't seem to work with Rails 5.

Comment: i think in the `welcome` method, he meant to do `premailer(mail to: user.email, subject: "Welcome")`

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the simple [premailer-rails gem](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails) I recently wrote. It uses Rails mailer hooks to do the conversion.

Answer (score 5):

For Rails 4 users you can: 
add the gems

```
gem 'premailer-rails'
gem 'nokogiri' (if you don't have it)
```

add this to your stylesheet (Haml):

```
%style{type:"text/css"}= Rails.application.assets.find_asset('email_stylesheet').to_s
```

for some reason it wasn't working with a normal stylesheet_link_tag

That's all I had to do. Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

or

```
gem "actionmailer_inline_css"
```